# Reduce the number of loop or code readability issues

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code is working as expected but is there a way to reduce the number of loops or improve the readability of this code to ES6/ES7 way? As you can see I am repeating the number of `.split` and `.join`

It will convert `Total.Subtotal": "10.50` into an array with the fields names and update string.

```
  {
    "Update": "+Total.+Subtotal = val:TotalSubtotal",
    "Field": {
      "+Total": "Total",
      "+Subtotal": "Subtotal"
    },
    "Value": {
      "val:TotalSubtotal": "10.50"
    }
  }
```

```js
function createMap(val) {
    const maps = [];

    Object.keys(val).forEach(entry => {
      const param = entry.split('.').join('');
      const names = {};

      for(const name of entry.split('.')) {
        names[`+${name}`] = name;
      }

      const setName = Object.keys(names).join(".");

      maps.push({
        Update: `${setName} = val:${param}`,
        Field: names,
        Value: { [`val:${param}`]: val[entry] },
      });
    });

    return maps;
  }


  console.log(
    createMap({
        "Total.Subtotal": "10.50"
    })
  )
```

Comment: Questions on optimizing working code are more suitable on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

1. Move any repeated logic up earlier into the function and reuse, this means you are only computing once.
2. Try using array methods like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which will avoid you having to write weird for loops etc

```js
function createMap(val) {
  return Object.keys(val).map(entry => {
    const splitValues = entry.split('.');
    const param = splitValues.join('');
    const names = splitValues.reduce((obj, currentValue) => {
      return { ...obj, [`+${currentValue}`]: currentValue };
    }, {});

    const setName = Object.keys(names).join('.');

    return {
      Update: `${setName} = val:${param}`,
      Field: names,
      Value: { [`val:${param}`]: val[entry] }
    };
  });
}

console.log(
  createMap({
    'Total.Subtotal': '10.50'
  })
);
```